# What are the chance of procing lava pool in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/hellfire-ring

> Chance on hit to engulf the ground in lava, dealing 200% weapon damage
>   per second for 6 seconds.

What are the chance?

I know that there are proc coefficient. However, I also know that the proc coefficient is there to compensate that a character may hit several enemies at once.

So does that mean on average we got that ground in lave every time we hit?

Say we uses normal attack. The proc coeficient is 1. So everytime we hit we got a pool of lava.

Then we uses I don't know, some sort of energy beam or earthquake or meteor or whatever that damage all enemies on screen and beyond. The proc coeficient may be low but we hit more enemies. So the chance on hit will still be 1?

Can't be that good.

What am I missing?

Comment: Apart from proc rate, there is also an internal cooldown, so you'd get a pool of lava "every time, but not more than once each X seconds". I wasn't able to find the proc coefficient (or ICD) on the Internet, but, combined with the damage, it is not worth it. 200% dps is really low, considering you get 320% from the most basic Bash, and people do not report being able to stack lava pools in any significant way. In general, Hellfire Ring is only useful for its XP boost - maybe that's why no one has bothered to test this :-)

Comment: OrcJMR is right, most aoes in this game do not stack, and 200% weapon damage is pure junk.  You are far better off wearing the standard meta rings (F&R, CoE, travelers set, etc)

Comment: And the xp boost has been nerfed like hell

Comment: Only on high levels, so it can't be used to farm Paragon, only for leveling characters.